# Extract nth line of text from strings in list- Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that consists of 149 text strings. From each string, I would like to extract the 2nd and 7th lines of text. I'd like the results of each line to be put in a separate list.

I've tried (just for one line):

```
text = []  
for string in list:
  x = string.splitlines()[2]
  text.append(x)
```

But I get the message "IndexError: list index out of range". I thought maybe I needed to do:

```
text = []  
for string in list:
  x = [string].splitlines()[2]
  text.append(x)
```

But that gave me the message "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'"

I'm using Python 3.6. Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You definitely didn't need to put it in brackets, that makes it a list. `string.splitlines` was correct, you just don't have 3 lines in that specific entry, apparently. (Without knowing what your data looks like, I can't say much more)

Comment: What is printed if you do `print(len(string.splitlines()))` right before assigning x in your first attempt?

Comment: Also, to extract the second line you should use `string.splitlines()[1]` - as 0 is the first element, 1 is the second and so on.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Thank you for the note about brackets. I didn't know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string.splitlines` is the correct function to split the lines of each string, and if it gives an `IndexError` for index 2 (note: this is the 3rd line) then that means that there are fewer than three lines.  This is probably the code you're looking for:

```
line2_results = []
line7_results = []
for str in list:
    lines = str.splitlines()
    if len(lines) >= 2:
        line2_results.append(lines[1])
        if len(lines) >= 7:
            line7_results.append(lines[6])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yes, there were blank strings in the input list and I see now that this was causing the error.